# When are event tiles assigned?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

Most maps have 2 event tiles, identified by sparkles or dots on the tile. If a unit stands on one of these tiles, they may get more experience, weapon proficiency, or an item. At what point (map start, tile activation) is the type (and exact item) of the event tiles generated?

Answer (score 1):

The effect of the tile is randomly chosen when one of your units ends their turn on it.

This effect is randomly chosen based on the unit that activates it, so it needs to be done at time of activation. For example, if paired units activate it those units can have their relationship improved as an effect.

Comment: Not entirely true, Maxed out characters can still trigger exp gain / wep exp but with no effect, just as an S relationship pair can trigger the relationship exp tile event

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I actually meant to modify this answer the other day when I had that happen. I'll remove that sentence now to reflect that, but the answer to the question still holds true.

Comment: I don't think that this is the case.  If I re-load a save multiple times from a point just before stepping on the event tile, the event tile is **always** the same.

Comment: Interesting. Reloading like that is only possible in casual mode, although I tried reloading multiple times from the chapter preparations on a map with an event tile that I could get to on my first move. I got Alm's Blade the first time, experience four times in a row, weapon experience once, then Roy's Blade. It's possible that a random number is chosen for each event tile at the beginning of the battle or turn, and then that number determines what happens depending on whether a single or paired unit lands on it.

Comment: `Maxed out characters can still trigger exp gain / wep exp but with no effect` Interesting to note: Even Taguel and Manakete can trigger the weapon-exp gain, even though they don't have any weapon to gain exp for.